# How to copy code from Visual Studio Code to OneNote with indentation?

Tags: microsoft-onenote, visual-studio-code

When I copy code form VS Code to OneNote, indentation is lost.

Example:
*This is how code on VS Code looks like:*
[image]

*When it's pasted to OneNote, it looks like this (indentation is lost):*
[image]

I wonder is there any way to copy code to OneNote without losing indentation.

---

Tried actions that didn't solve the problem:

- *Converting indentation to tabs or spaces on VS Code doesn't work.*

  - > if you use "spaces" for your indentation then change that to
    >   "tabs"using the below steps and then copy the code to oneNote.
    >
    > **Steps:**
    >
    > - 'ctrl + shift + p'
    > - find command "convert indentation to tabs"
    > - copy the code and paste it in oneNote
    >
    >   quote from [Dark Light's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1294951/371227)

---

Side observations:

- It works perfectly when pasting code to Word. *It looks like this when pasted to Word:*

  - [image]

Comment: You're Question is really confusing. 1st your talking about OneNote not Supporting code highlighting. Then you're complaining about loosing Indentation on copying Code over to OneNote. That are two really different Things. Can you please reword your Question

Answer (score 3):

if you use "spaces" for your indentation then change that to "tabs"using the below steps and then copy the code to oneNote.

**Steps:**

- 'ctrl + shift + p'
- find command "convert indentation to tabs"
- copy the code and paste it in oneNote

This works for me.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, either for indentation as tabs or spaces.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, OneNote isn't a code editor nor an IDE so it doesn't have built-in code highlighting nor does it have code completition, so if your changing copied over code it won't automatically change its color like the IDE or the code editor would.

Speaking of indentation, this is no special metadata content but rather just normal text data content, so it should be copied over. Keep in mind in most IDEs and code editors you can select whether a tab will insert spaces (most likely 2 or 4) or a tab, while in OneNote a tab will always be a tab.

I just did a quick test by copying some code out of VS Code to OneNote and the indentation didn't get lost. Also, the highlighting colors were still there.

So I guess either your VS Code or your OneNote settings may be set up in a special way that causes it to not do what you like.

Comment: When i copy code out of VS Code to OneNote last week, it's indentation didn't get lost.
But now it's didn;'t work, i haven't change any settings.

Comment: Can you get me a copy of your VS Code user settings.

Comment: IIRC code copied from VS Code (and other highlighting editors, e.g. Notepad++) does preserve colour information, since they are copied (and pasted) in a rich text mode by default. But that's not the OP's question, anyway - they said the highlighting is preserved while the indentation is not (post-edit). You are correct re: indentation just being normal text characters.